# Calculate timing in cpp

Tags: c++, std

I am writing a sorting program and to analyse timing I am using **std::chrono**

When I am calling its members like this, my program says it took **0 nanoseconds** to sort the array

```
auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();

insertion_sort(Data, SIZE);

auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end - start);

cout<<"Sorting time is "<<duration.count()<<" nanoseconds...";
```

Array has 100 elements, my sorting algorithm looks like this

```
void insertion_sort(int* data, int size){
int insertionPlace = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0 && data[j-1]>data[j];j--) {
        insertionPlace++;
        int tmp = data[j - 1];
        data[j-1] = data[j];
        data[j] = tmp;
    }
}
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You should use `steady_clock` for timing. You don't want a clock that could be non-monotonic.

Comment: I'd also suggest using a LOT more than 100 elements. Even a bubble sort will complete that very quickly.

Comment: Your program is probably compiled with the highest optimization level (as it should) and it's possible that the compiler managed to optimize away all code doing the sorting. If you don't look at the result, it's allowed to just throw it away, because, who would notice? (the _as if_ rule). Suggestion: Fill `Data` with random data first and print `Data[0]` after you've printed the duration and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: `chrono` supports down to nanoseconds, but unless you're running on some really slick, custom crafted hardware you probably won't get time more accurate than microseconds and the resolution could be as bad as tens of milliseconds or in some extremely sad cases even seconds. This makes 3Dave's comment about needing more elements to sort utterly vital. You may need millions of elements before you can see anything.

Comment: Could you show what Data is ? Compiler with hight optimization level can optimize your code. You can also check all benchmark assembly in https://godbolt.org or in objdump assembly output.

Comment: @chris thank you, seems like it working exactly as I wanted it to work

Comment: @3Dave I see that my amount of data is not so big to make some difference, but my task is to analyse the algorithm in this case